# Selección de observaciones con un bucle y slice_sample que da el error "cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'"

Tags: r, bucles

Estoy intentando sacar de forma aleatoria una muestra y me surge un problema. La cosa es que yo quiero sacar una muestra de forma aleatoria a partir de establecer previamente unas cuotas. He sacado las cuotas que se necesitan de cada grupo para que sea representativa y luego he utilizado un código para sacar de forma aleatoria a los individuos. El problema se da porque, por ejemplo, si yo necesito a 3 hombres de Madrid de 20 a 30 años y en el Panel que estoy utilizando solo tengo a 2 hombres me da el siguiente error:

> "cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace =
> FALSE'"

Ya que he establecido que quiero más gente de ese grupo del que yo tengo en mi Panel. Mi pregunta es si sería posible establecer de alguna forma que cuando esto ocurra (que el número de individuos que tengo en un grupo dentro del Panel es menor que el establecido en las cuotas) seleccione directamente a todos los individuos sin que me salga ese error. El código que he utilizado es el siguiente:

n = nrow(targets) --> **aquí establezco el número de filas( los grupos por cuotas)**

muestra_list <- list()  --> **lista donde se irán guardando las bases de datos de cada grupo por el que segmentamos**

Y este es el bucle que me da error:

```r
for(i in 1:n){
muestra<- panel %>% filter(CCAA==targets$ccaa[[i]], 
                           Sexo==targets$Sexo[[i]], 
                           grupo_edad==targets$Edad[[i]]) %>%  slice_sample(n = targets$total[[i]])`
  
  muestra_list[[i]] <- muestra

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Una posibilidad es que uses el parámetro `replace = TRUE` en `slice_sample()` que lo que hará es repetir las filas tantas veces sea necesario para llegar al tamaño de muestra deseado.

Lo otro que podrías hacer, es construir la selección, contar las observaciones, compararla con el tamaño de la muestra y establecer la cantidad para `slice_sample()`:

```
for(i in 1:n) {
  muestra <- panel %>% 
    filter(CCAA==targets$ccaa[[i]], 
           Sexo==targets$Sexo[[i]], 
           grupo_edad==targets$Edad[[i]]) 
  
  cantidad <- ifelse(targets$total[[i]] > nrow(muestra), nrow(muestra), targets$total[[i]])
  muestra_list[[i]] <- slice_sample(muestra, n = cantidad)
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! solucionado el problema! :)